# How to add my block and phtml file in magento 2 with reference block

Tags: blocks, template, magento-2.1.3, creditmemo

I want to **add a text box on the total credit memo**. I can input amount to refund.

I am trying to add my block in `creditmemo_totals`

What i tried is 
add code in

**Company/Custom/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml**

```
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block class="Company\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Creditmemo\Totals" name="Company_fee" template="Company_Custom::creditmemo/companyfee.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

What i want to do is add custom fee total box in refund total box like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add fee box in refund total block we need to remove **adjustments** block using

```
<referenceBlock name="adjustments" remove="true"/>
```

and then add your block in creditmemo_totals reference

**Company/Custom/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml**

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adjustments" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="creditmemo_totals">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\Create\Adjustments" name="Company_fee" template="Company_Custom::creditmemo/ktplfee.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```